# What is the basis for Vaishampayana's claim that the Saraswati became invisible because of her contempt for Sudras and Abhiras?

Tags: mahabharata, saraswati, rivers, shudra

As [mentioned in the Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09037.htm):

> Vaishampayana said, "Then Valadeva, O king, proceeded to Vinasana where the Sarasvati hath become invisible in consequence of her contempt for Sudras and Abhiras. And since the Sarasvati, in consequence of such contempt, is lost at that spot, the Rishis, for that reason, O chief of the Bharatas, always name the place as Vinasana

When did Saraswati express contempt for Sudras and Abhiras and how did it make her invisible?

What is the basis for Vaishampayana's claim that the Saraswati became invisible because of her contempt for Sudras and Abhiras?

Comment: Question in title, answer in the body that the title is the reason. What are you exactly looking for? What do you mean by "What is Vaishampayana referring to"? (I didn't downvote though)

Answer (score 1):

This is a historical record of changing social status of 'manual working class' who were designated as 'Sudra' in the caste system. Before Maha Bharata period they must had enjoyed a greater social status.The contempt towards Sudra may refer to introduction of untouchability or some other devaluation.

Vaishampayana refers to this event poetically by accusing the goddess Sarasvati who was the mentor all Vedic scholars. Thus,the Rishi finds the reason for drying of the physical river Sarasvati in the failure of her role as mentor. And the name of that place 'Vinasana'- spread of destruction, is not less symbolic. Indeed the gloom periods of Hinduism started right after Maha Bharata period
And finally resulted in the sumission to Islamic Mughals and Christian British.

Comment: This answer is only an analysis of the theme raised in the question. Please refer which portion need a reference.